# can you help me setup DNS forwarding

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, unix, bind

I have a dns server in a subnet of the corporate network and i want to tell it to forward to the main dns servers when it cannot resolve

this is my file:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        forwarders { 10.90.0.135; 10.90.0.174; };
        forward first;
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";


zone "appletop.local" IN {
        type master;
        file "appletop.local";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

i know the dns server 10.90.0.35 is good and if i use it to resolve using dig its fine ie

```
[root@ns1 etc]# dig www.yahoo.com @10.90.0.135

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.0.2.el6_4.6 <<>> www.yahoo.com @10.90.0.135
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24437
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.yahoo.com.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.yahoo.com.          278     IN      CNAME   fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com.
fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com. 278     IN      CNAME   ds-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com.
ds-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com. 1       IN      CNAME   ds-eu-fp3-lfb.wa1.b.yahoo.com.
ds-eu-fp3-lfb.wa1.b.yahoo.com. 235 IN   CNAME   ds-eu-fp3.wa1.b.yahoo.com.
ds-eu-fp3.wa1.b.yahoo.com. 26   IN      A       87.248.122.122
ds-eu-fp3.wa1.b.yahoo.com. 26   IN      A       87.248.112.181

;; Query time: 49 msec
;; SERVER: 10.90.0.135#53(10.90.0.135)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep 12 17:37:15 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 167
```

but i cannot get it to forward any of my normal requests to that server

what have i done wrong im copying the entrys from examples on the net but it doesnt work

thank you

Answer (score 2):

the problem was i had enable dns-sec in the file - i removed all the sec stuff and it worked

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

```
allow-recursion { 192.168.0.0/24; };
```

to the bind options? Where 192.168.0.0/24 is your local subnet.

Can you post the results of a:

```
dig @yourdnsserver www.yahoo.com
```

?

You might consider adding these to your question rather than my response

===Edits from requester below===
dig hangs:

> dig +trace www.yahoo.com
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.0.2.el6_4.6 <<>> +trace
>   www.yahoo.com ;; global options: +cmd .                       518400 
>   IN      NS      H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN
>   NS      G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. .                       518400  IN      NS
>   B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.

also var/log/messages is full of :

```
> Sep 12 18:08:51 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: validating @0x7fef184578a0: .
> NS: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure Sep 12
> 18:08:51 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (insecurity proof failed)
> resolving './NS/IN': 10.90.0.174#53 Sep 12 18:08:51 ns1
> named-sdb[25026]: validating @0x7fef184b2ea0: . NS: got insecure
> response; parent indicates it should be secure Sep 12 18:08:51 ns1
> named-sdb[25026]: error (insecurity proof failed) resolving './NS/IN':
> 10.90.0.135#53 Sep 12 18:08:53 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'NET/DS/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53 Sep 12 18:08:55
> ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN':
> 2001:503:c27::2:30#53 Sep 12 18:08:57 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error
> (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53 Sep 12
> 18:08:58 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (network unreachable) resolving
> 'NET/DS/IN': 2001:503:c27::2:30#53 Sep 12 18:09:01 ns1
> named-sdb[25026]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'NET/DS/IN':
> 2001:500:3::42#53 Sep 12 18:09:01 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (no
> valid DS) resolving 'F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET/A/IN': 10.90.0.174#53 Sep 12
> 18:09:01 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (no valid DS) resolving
> 'F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET/AAAA/IN': 10.90.0.174#53 Sep 12 18:09:01 ns1
> named-sdb[25026]: error (no valid DS) resolving
> 'E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET/A/IN': 10.90.0.174#53 Sep 12 18:09:05 ns1
> named-sdb[25026]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'NET/DS/IN':
> 2001:500:1::803f:235#53 Sep 12 18:09:09 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error
> (network unreachable) resolving 'NET/DS/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53 Sep 12
> 18:09:09 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (network unreachable) resolving
    > 'NET/DS/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53 Sep 12 18:09:09 ns1 named-sdb[25026]:
> error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53 Sep
> 12 18:09:11 ns1 named-sdb[25026]: error (network unreachable)
> resolving 'NET/DS/IN': 2001:dc3::35#53
```

Comment: try removing the `recursion` and `allow-recursion` lines? It looks like you cannot contact root DNS servers (Network admin likely blocking clients from reaching outside of network for dns).